# PHP file_get_contents blocked on my server

Tags: php, web-applications, server, header-files, file-get-contents

I have problems retrieving the data that an external server sends to me. I'll explain better: to change the status of a record in my database, I contact an external application, which sends to the application I've created the result of the call in the header.

Now, my question is: if I have `file_get_contents("php://input")` blocked or restricted in my server, do I have an alternative solution to retrieve that data? If yes, what does it is?

EDIT: here's an example of code.

```
//the function will be called every time the external server calls my file
function remoteValidation(){
    $requestData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($requestData) && !empty($requestData) && $requestData['signature'] == $this->savedSignature) {
        // validation on the signature
    } else {
        throw new Exception ('The signature is not valid, or is empty!);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your server is blocking “Remote Server Connection”. Please contact your host provider to allow “file_get_contents()” php function.

Comment: This question seems a little muddled - is an external server connecting to your server (e.g. someone is making a POST request to your server), or is your server attempting to connect to an external server (cURL to an API maybe)?

Comment: Can you supply some example code please? I understand your question like so: Your application is called from an outside server and you want to access the body of the request?
On the other hand, you mention the header. If the information you're looking for is in the header, there would be other ways to get it.

Comment: @ahuemmer I've edited the post to provide an example of code.

Comment: @CD001 the external server calls a specific file of my application, and every time the server calls it I trigger the function "remoteValidation" like in the code example above (which is inside the file called. I just trigger it from the constructor of the object).

Comment: Presumably the remote application is sending the data in a `POST` request rather than `GET`? Otherwise `file_get_contents("php://input")` won't work and you'd be better off just using `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents("php://input")` will give you the *raw* data, so you won't be able to access it as an array (like in `$requestData['signature']`). You would first have to parse in according to its "real" format (like `json_decode` if it is JSON).

Alternatives - if you're definitely not able to use `file_get_contents("php://input")` on your server - would be using a `GET` request als @CD001 stated or possibly using the request *headers* to transfer your information.

If you have no influence on how the external server sends the data to you, it could be possible to use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` - but please note that you shouldn't to so if you can avoid it as is deprecated and was removed in PHP7 anyway.